# Unable to Install Python 3.11 With Pyenv

Tags: python, python-3.x

Our school project requires us to use the cmu_graphics library in a local directory to generate an image. Since cmu_graphics does not have support for python 3.12, I am using pyenv to install python 3.11:

`pyenv install 3.11`

But this is returned

```
~ % pyenv install 3.11
python-build: use openssl@3 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.11.7.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.7/Python-3.11.7.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.11.7...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.7.3 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20240130084550.73534
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20240130084550.73534.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/python-build.20240130084550.73534/Python-3.11.7':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I tried to reinstall make with

`brew reinstall make`

expecting the makefile error to be fixed but the same error is returned

Comment: what Operating System are you using?

Comment: am facing the same issue, OS: MAC

Comment: I am using MACos